# Probability that we have a valid pdf given pdf of its parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, continuity

Say, $f_X(x) = Y \frac{1}{x^A} $ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Now, we have $ Y \sim normal(A,1), A \sim uniform(0,1)$. Sampling uniformly for $A$ and $Y$, what is the probability that $f_X$ is a valid pdf (i.e. its integral over the support = 1)?

My intuition tells me that the conditional probability that, given $A = a$, $P[f_X(x)$ is a valid pdf] = 0, because given arbitrary $A = a$, $\exists! y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ s.t. $f_X(x) = y\frac{1}{x^a}$ is a pdf (and specifically, $y = \frac{1}{\int f_X(x)} \chi_{[0,1]} dx$. But then, ${y}$ is a set of measure 0.

How would you find the unconditional probability, however?

Comment: The set of valid pairs $(A, Y)$ is a curve in the strip $[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$. If $A$ and $Y$ are independent, the probability that $(A, Y)$ lies on this curve is zero.

Comment: @angryavian the way I define it above, is it the case that A and Y are independent?

Comment: You haven't specified the joint distribution of $(A, Y)$, so I cannot say.